# Doctrine dbl with LIKE and a parameter error

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

What am I dong wrong here?

```
return $em->createQuery("
    SELECT p FROM SomeBundle:Page p
    WHERE p.title LIKE '%?1%'")
    ->setParameters(array($q))
```

Gives me a

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Seems to be because the param is in quotes, but without, it does not work either...

On Doctrine 2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it interprets it as a string with ?1 in it. 
Why just not wrap the value into '%'?

```
return $em->createQuery("
    SELECT p FROM SomeBundle:Page p
    WHERE p.title LIKE ?0")
    ->setParameters(array("%{$q}%"))
```

Comment: for my excuse, t'was like this in the docs... http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples still a dumb question. Thanks!